# OpenAPI to generate schemas for implementations whitout adding @Schema annotation on interface

Tags: java, openapi

Problem:
I would like to have schemas for implementations of interfaces without adding @Schema annotation on interface due to number of interfaces in existing system.

Example:

```
@Schema( oneOf = { ResultOne.class, ResultTwo.class } )
public interface Result
```

Gives me:

```
components: class Components {
        schemas: {Result=class ComposedSchema {
            class Schema {
                ...
            }
            allOf: null
            anyOf: null
            oneOf: [class Schema {
                type: null
                format: null
                $ref: #/components/schemas/ResultOne
                ...
            }, class Schema {
                type: null
                format: null
                $ref: #/components/schemas/ResultTwo
                ...
            }]
        }, ResultOne=class Schema {
            ...
        }, ResultTwo=class Schema {
            ...
        }}
}
```

Does anyone know how to tell to OpenAPI that should generate schemas for implementations in such way programmatically? Without adding annotation to intefaces?